# woocommerce_before_shop_loop (Result Count and Catalog Ordering) not show in custom archive template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have created a simple custom archive template in my woocommerce theme.
archive-type.php
It is exactly a copy of archive-product.php, and it's works correctly.
But not show **Result Count** and **Catalog Ordering**

How can i fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add your code. I am unfamiliar with [tag:woocomerce] (wc) and maybe others know that `archive-product.php` is a page that is part of wc and can tell you why on your copy `archive-type.php` the values Result Count and Catalog Ordering are not displayed. But i assume that if you add your code (php, javscript and generated html) it will be easier for others to help. Are there any message on the console of your browser?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer.
It's exactly a copy of archive-product.php of woocommerce but renamed:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php

Comment: Do you mean `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );` [starting on line 46](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php#L46)? Where is `have_posts()` defined?